# Merging devices in Windows 7 Devices and Printers

Tags: windows-7

My company makes a product that includes both a display and a USB input device. Right now they show up as two separate icons in Devices and Printers, and we'd obviously like them to be exposed as one.

According to the documentation at [MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/device/deviceexperience/containerids.mspx), the way to do this is to provide a `ContainerID` through one means or another, but display devices are not mentioned at all. Does anyone have an idea how to manage the `ContainerID` of a display device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to someone at Microsoft, this is currently not possible:

http://www.osronline.com/showthread.cfm?link=195254

Answer (score -1):

http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2010/03/02/windows-7-where-are-my-printers.aspx

fix. but it's aesthetic anyway, if you right-click the printer and hover over properties, you can choose props for each individual printer, and they're seperately selectable in printer choice drop-downs, such as in word > file/ribbon > Print [choose either & go].

But either way, if you're after a fix, the link is above.

Comment: Could you please clarify this answer, since it starts in the middle of a sentence?